# Comment utiliser le verbe « poindre » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, verbes-défectifs

Certaines tables de conjugaison le considèrent défectif et d'autres non.

*Poindre* se conjuguerait de plusieurs manières ou, en fait,  n'y en aurait-il  qu'une seule ? Quelle est l'explication ?

Answer (score 4):

Le verbe « poindre » s'emploie de nos jours essentiellement à l'infinitif, au participe présent et à la troisième personne du singulier du présent et du futur de l'indicatif.

« Poindre » au **sens propre** veut dire « piquer ». De nos jours on retrouve ce sens propre dans l'emploi au participe présent :

> Une douleur poignante.

En fait cet emploi est considéré comme un adjectif.

Au **sens figuré** « poindre » veut dire « apparaître » (à la façon d'une pointe), on le trouve essentiellement à l'infinitif :

> [L'UE voit poindre un Brexit sans accord](https://www.24heures.ch/monde/direct-royaumeuni-retient-souffle/story/12784625).

> [Huawei verrait-il poindre le bout du tunnel ?](https://www.01net.com/actualites/trump-permet-a-huawei-de-reprendre-ses-echanges-avec-les-entreprises-americaines-1723213.html)

et parfois à la troisième personne du singulier au présent :

> [Le jour point sur les champs nus de la Somme](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/economie/transports/gilets-jaunes/s-il-faut-etre-la-a-noel-et-au-nouvel-an-on-sera-la-les-gilets-jaunes-d-albert-pres-d-amiens-mobilises-depuis-le-premier-jour_3085581.html)...

> Nous partirons quand le jour poindra.

personnellement je considère cet emploi comme relativement littéraire et poétique et pas d'un usage courant.

Mettre dans un tableau de conjugaison des [formes telles que](http://www.conjugaison-verbe.fr/conjugaison/verbe/poindre.htm) « je poignais », « nous poignions » me semble ridicule, et même [ceux](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/poindre.php) qui montrent bien que le verbe « poindre » est défectif (c'est à dire qu'il n'existe pas à toutes les formes) ne devrait pas faire paraître des temps tels que l'imparfait ou le subjonctif.

Comment: Je suspecte d'ailleurs que la plupart des locuteurs ignorent le lien entre poindre et poignant et seraient bien incapable de produire spontanément des formes comme ils poignaient

Comment: Je ne rejoins pas cet avis et aurais plutôt tendance à penser que le verbe poindre est plutôt utilisé au passé (passé composé ou imparfait), ex: *j'ai poigné*, d'ailleurs je ne soupçonnais même pas son infinitif.

Comment: @stbr « J'ai poigné » est le passé composé du verbe « poigner » (toucher avec le point).  Le participe passé du verbe « poindre » est « point » (ex. au passé composé :  *le jour a point*). Quant à l'imparfait, mis à part quelque chose comme « cette histoire me poignait » (que je n'ai jamais dite ou entendue mais comprendrais), je ne vois guère d'exemple dans la langue contemporaine, et surtout pas à la première personne. Je trouve que [cet article](https://www.la-croix.com/Archives/2008-04-12/Poindre.-_NP_-2008-04-12-317373) que je viens de trouver résume bien la situation.

Comment: @Laure Ca doit sans doute être un abus de langage, j'ai toujours entendu *j'ai poigné* synonyme de *j'ai flippé* ou *j'ai eu peur*, ce verbe étant peu utilisé, ça ne m'étonnerait guère. Je parlais bien entendu d'une expression plutôt orale (et peut-être même relevant plus de l'argot ou du langage familier), donc forcément absente des ouvrages ou de la littérature. Concernant le premier point, vous vouliez dire toucher avec le poinG non ? Ca porte à confusion.

Comment: @ Oui bien sûr avec le poin**g**, merci d'avoir rectifié.  Je ne connais pas l'expression "j'ai poigné" (pour j'ai flippé), question de générations je suppose, pas toujours évident de suivre l'évolution des mots. Le verbe poigner/pogner est d'ailleurs lui aussi peu utilisé mais peut s'employer à la première personne.

Comment: Au Québec le verbe [_pogner_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pogner) est vraiment courant à l'oral, pour _attraper_ entre autres. [_Pogner les nerfs_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pogner_les_nerfs) rejoint probablement le truc avec _flipper_...